# python does not recognise lxml

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, upgrade

got a question 
just upgraded to python 3, uninstalled 2.7 and now when I try to compile the line `from lxml import html`

I get

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Samin/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/python3", line 2, in <module>
    from lxml import html 
ImportError: No module named lxml
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/Samin/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/python3"]
[dir: /Users/Samin/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

despite the fact that I have done pip3 install lxml and it says requirement already satisfied  in library/frameworks/python.framework/versions/lib/python3.5/site-packages

I have a feeling this will now be a recurring problem for packages outside of python 3.5 so would love some help to know why this is happening

much love 
thank you for reading this x

EDIT: is this by any chance happening because the packages directory is in the sublime text 3 packages directory and thats not where I just installed lxml??

Comment: ST3 uses it's own version of [lxml](https://github.com/eerohele/sublime-lxml) that it should download automatically if it isn't already there, it should be within `/Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages`. It can also be seen through `Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Browse Packages`